# How to make task depend on another in sbt 0.12?

Tags: sbt

I'm using SBT `0.12.0`.

I've two tasks in my `project/Build.scala` - `helloTask` and `u2` defined as follows:

```
val hello = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "Prints 'Hello World'")

val helloTask = hello := {
  println("Hello World")
}

val u2Task = TaskKey[Unit]("u2") := { println("u2") }
```

How to make `u2` task depend on `hellotask`? I used `<<=` following the sample as described in [Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks) (in the original version of the question it was https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks, but the doc has since moved and changed).

```
u2Task <<= u2Task dependsOn helloTask
```

But I got `reassignment to val` error. Apparently, I cannot get anything with `<<=` to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. I misunderstood the `<<=` and `:=` operators as assignment operators.

```
  val hello = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "Prints 'Hello World'")

  val helloTask = hello := {
     println("Hello World")
  }

  val u2 = TaskKey[Unit]("u2", "print u2")
  val u2Task = u2 <<= hello map {_ => println("u2")}
```

and the result

```
> u2
Hello World
u2
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't see you following the sample very closely - this works for me:

```
  val helloTask = TaskKey[String]("hello")
  val u2Task = TaskKey[Unit]("u2") 

  helloTask := {
    println("Hello World")
    "Hello World"
  }

  u2Task := {println("u2")} 

  u2Task <<= u2Task.dependsOn (helloTask)
```

The precise reason is that your definition of u2Task has a different type, you can see in the REPL:

```
scala> val u2Task = TaskKey[Unit]("u2")
u2Task: sbt.TaskKey[Unit] = sbt.TaskKey$$anon$3@101ecc2

scala> val u2Task = TaskKey[Unit]("u2") := {println("u2")}
u2Task: sbt.Project.Setting[sbt.Task[Unit]] = setting(ScopedKey(Scope(This,This,This,This),u2))
```

Comment: Could you get that to work ?. Could you post your full config file ? Because I got an error (http://pastebin.com/Tw8REnt5). And here is my build file (http://pastebin.com/L5kAW36v). I used sbt 0.12.0 here.

Comment: That's a different question. Your build definition looks weird to me, you're adding a ++= statement in the middle of the libraryDependencies. I'm not an sbt expert, but that looks weird.

Comment: It did work with my task definition that I used before. I got this style from scalaz and scala-graph project. By the way, how did you include sbt in console and inspect it ? I want to give it a try so I might figure something out.

Comment: console-project will launch Scala with your build definition loaded.

Comment: @Tg That error just looks like you have your brackets in the wrong place. i.e. use `settings = defaultSettings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= coreDependencies) ++ Seq(helloTask)`

Comment: @Luke, I messed up a little bit when I was cleaning up unnecessary thing for example. The real one doesn't have mis-placing paren. Thanks for warning anyway. :)