# Test cleanup hook not executed in scala play application

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Below is my Build.scala file

There is no error in test, but the cleanup hook is not executed after test
what is the issue?

```
import play.Project._
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object AppBuild extends Build {
  val appName = "test"
  val appVersion = "1.0"

  val dependencies = Seq(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0.RC1"
  )

  val main = play.Project(
    appName, appVersion,
    dependencies,
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings
  )
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.1",
    testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup (
      () => println("Cleanup")
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup
```

does not work with forked test runs as mentioned in [another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346140/sbt-doesnt-call-test-setup-on-a-play2-project).

But there are workarounds:

**Set fork to false**

This is simple but may slow down your tests because they won't be executed in parallel.

```
sbt.Keys.fork in Test := false
```

**Use the test framework**

For example http://doc.scalatest.org/1.9.2/index.html#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll with the protected method afterAll()

**Override the test task**

My favorite.

```
test in Test ~= { testTask =>
  val result = testTask
  println("Cleanup")
  result
}
```

Comment: 1) fork false : works  
2) Cannot use BeforeAndAfterAll : because, I need to execute methods before and after all tests  
3) Your fav : also works, but is it possible to add a before hook?

Comment: You can add a before task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964583/sbt-how-to-make-one-task-depend-on-other